# How do I ship multiple interdependent apps on macOS?

Tags: macos, installation

I'm building a hobbyist game engine. It consists of two executables, the game and the editor, which share many resources. Also, the editor may start the game as a child process.

On Windows, I can just install the executables in the same folder and they would both show up in the start menu.

On Linux, both executables may share the same lib/foo and share/foo.

What am I supposed to do on macOS? IIUC, an app bundle may only have a single main executable. As both apps share most resources (such as libraries, graphics, sounds, etc.) it doesn't feel right to just deploy them as separate bundles.

One solution would be to create a "launcher" app as the main executable which would just show a dialog and let the user choose the actual app. In fact, this is what LibreOffice does on macOS. On Windows, you can either run the "LibreOffice" launcher app, or you can directly run individual apps, such as "LibreOffice Writer". On macOS, there is only the launcher app. It is not terrible, but it still feels a bit awkward and unnecessary, at least coming from Windows and Linux.

Any other ideas? What would you consider most idiomatic?

Comment: I'm not a macOS developer, but I seem to remember that the container folders in `~/Library` that your app can use _can_ be shared among a group of apps by the same developer…? Perhaps that was just for iOS, but since the two systems grow ever more similar, this might exist on macOS too. It might require using an installer, or for the app to create those resources at runtime, which would either require shipping the assets with both apps or downloading them on first launch, but that might be an option.

Comment: @deceze I think that won't work because the OP needs to share code between the two executables. Apple does not allow for code from one bundle to point to another outside bundle (apart from their own) as that causes security risks.

Comment: @jvarela Fair enough; as I said, it was just something I vaguely knew a little about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have such a Mac app, which has many helpers apart from the main executable. You can indeed choose to have a launcher and then ask the user to choose what they want to do, but I agree that's awkward.

I think what you need to ask yourself is: which of the two apps is going to be the most used? The game or the editor? If it is the game, I would package the editor as a helper of game, and this one would be the main executable and I would add an UI button or a menu item to the game for the user to start the editor from the game. If the editor is the most used app, I would reason the other way round.

I would then package the Mac app as follows:

```
MyApp.app
   /Contents
      Info.plist
      /Frameworks
          YourSharedCode.framework
      /MacOS
          MainExecutable
          Helper
      /Resources
          MainExcutable.icns
          ...
```

Indeed, you should only have one main executable, but you can package more than one executable inside your bundle's `MacOS` folder according to the latest Apple's [recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle). You can always tell to MacOS which executable is the main one in your `Info.plist` file. In `Frameworks` I would put all the shared code between the two executables and in `Resources` all shared resources.

Comment: Thanks!

`which of the two apps is going to be the most used? The game or the editor?`

It really depends on the use case. That's why I'll probably stick with a launcher app.

If I want to ship a game without the editor (to save space), I would only have to modify the `Info.plist`. Or the launcher could just automatically start the game, if it doesn't find the editor executable.